# RecyclerView - GridLayoutManager - scroll in both directions

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, scroll, android-recyclerview

currently I'm looking for an GridLayoutManager for the RecyclerView with which I can scroll in both directions.
It should have an fixed number of columns. But if those columns are too width, there should be an scrollbar with which I can scroll horizontal.

The number of rows is undefined and should be calculated based on the number of items.

I created a small picture to clarify what I mean.
[image: picture to clarify what I mean]

I already searched on google, but until now I could not find anything, which fits my requirements.
Is there anybody who knows such a layoutmanager?

My current solution is to wrap an HorizontalScrollView around the RecyclerView.
And I already created a subclass of GridLayoutManager and override canScrollHorizontal() and canScrollVertical(). But this doesn't work.

Comment: Have you figured out a better solution yet? The HorizontalScrollView has been working best for me so far, even NestedScrollView wasn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Try this project: https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground

There is [FixedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/299515e0cfe4caea78eaf7ba12f7c9cf926b6063/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/layout/FixedGridLayoutManager.java).

[image]